# EnvDTE Visual Studio 2013 : get the progID?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, progid

I am trying to create a Visual Studio instance using :

```
EnvDTE80.DTE2 dte2;
dte2 = (EnvDTE80.DTE2)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.12.0");
```

And I am always having the exception "Invalid Class String" so I assume that the problem is "VisualStudio.DTE.12.0". 
But I am working on Visual Studio 2013 12.0.30501, I also tried to put only "VisualStudio.DTE" to get the most recent version, and same exception.

Also, I tried the other way :

```
Type t = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("VisualStudio.DTE.12.0", true);
dte2 = (EnvDTE80.DTE2)System.Activator.CreateInstance(t, true);
```

The problem is still there, I am running a bit out of idea... Is it really an invalid string error ?

Comment: No, that's the correct ProgID if you have VS2013.  Your registry must be broken, use Regedit.exe to have a look at HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.DTE.12.0.  With the expectation that you cannot find it.

Comment: This is correct, I can't find the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.DTE.12.0 in regedit. How am I supposed to "create" it ?

Comment: Your machine is broken.  Heavens knows what else disappeared.  Feel free to panic.  Re-running the VS installer might work.

Comment: Well, thank you very much I will try to solve it this way !

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Visual Studio 2013 Express this works to fix it:

```
Type t = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("WDExpress.DTE.12.0", true);
var x = (EnvDTE80.DTE2)System.Activator.CreateInstance(t, true);
```